# Controller Extention returning null value

Tags: apex

Below is my controller extention code. i am getting null value for acct.Owner field. Dnt know what i am doing wrong here.

And how can i filter record value like, return only that record 'where createdById =userid'

```
public class myControllerExtension {



    private final Event_Request__c acct;
    public myControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {

                acct = (Event_Request__c)controller.getRecord();
    }


    public String getEvent() {
            return ''+acct.Owner ; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field `Owner` is a reference to a `User` object; the field `OwnerId` is the ID of a `User` that perhaps you could use for filtering (though you would probably need to use [addFields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardController_addFields.htm) too to get the StandardController to query the field).

But if you want to query some SObjects owned by the currently active user you just need a query of this form:

```
select ... from ... where OwnerId = :UserInfo.getUserId()
```

See [UserInfo.getUserId](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm#apex_System_UserInfo_getUserId).

**PS**

An example of addFields:

```
public myControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
    if (!Test.isRunningTest()) {
        sc.addFields(new String[] {String.valueOf(Account.OwnerId)});
    }
    ...
```

This is using the field token so there is a compile-time check but you can also use a string for the API name of the field i.e. `'OwnerId'` instead of `String.valueOf(Account.OwnerId)`.

Comment: can you write an example of addFields to get the Stdcontroller to query the field?

Comment: @puravthakkar Added as a PS.